# Populate a single ObjectId reference after aggregating with mongoDb and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to populate after aggregating and counting.

These are mye models:

UserLog

```
const UserLog = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    article: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Article',
      required: true,
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } }
);
```

Article

```
const Article = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } }
);
```

And I am running a query like this:

```
export const getCountByArticle = async () => {
  const articles = await UserLog.aggregate([
    {
      $group: { _id: '$article', count: { $sum: 1 } },
    },
  ]);
  return articles;
};
```

The query returns this:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5fcbc12dd895b528289723e6",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fccefc375c47a3fd49c083d",
            "count": 2
        }
    ],
```

The problem is that i want to "populate" the _id field with the actual article. I have tried $lookup, but that returns an array with all of the articles, and I dont want that. Unwind is not working for me either. Under is how i actually want the result to be.

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5fcbc12dd895b528289723e6",
            "title": "Title",
            "content": "contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fccefc375c47a3fd49c083d",
            "title": "Title",
            "content": "contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent",
            "count": 2
        }
    ],
```

I really hope that someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) pipeline step after the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage in your aggregate operation that does a similar job to Mongoose's populate and reshape your documents stream using [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) in the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to merge the joined documents from $group and $lookup array:

```
export const getCountByArticle = async () => {
    const articles = await UserLog.aggregate([
        { $group: { 
            _id: '$article', count: { $sum: 1 } 
        } },
        { $lookup: {
            from: 'articles',
            localField: '_id',    
            foreignField: '_id',  
            as: 'articles'
        } },
        { $replaceRoot: { 
            newRoot: { 
                $mergeObjects: [ 
                    { $arrayElemAt: [ '$articles', 0 ] }, 
                    '$$ROOT' 
                ] 
            } 
        } },
        { $project: { articles: 0 } }
    ]).exec();
  
    return articles;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$lookup`for MongoDB > 3.2

```
{ 
   "$lookup" : {
        from: "name of lookup collection",
        localField: "field in the input collection",
        foreignField: "field in the lookup collection",
        as: "field name for the output documents"
     }
 }
```